# Create a Highcharts Polar chart with lines rather than segments

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to create a HighCharts Polar chart, something like the wind rose sample, but instead of columns being rendered as segments, I want to draw lines - something like this:

[image: polar chart]

Anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 2):

You could make every line a series in the following way:

```
series: [{
    name: 'Line 1',
    data: [{x:0, y: 0}, {x: 0, y: 43000}],
    pointPlacement: 'on'
  },
  ...
]
```

The above creates a line at 0 degrees, from 0 to 43000.

**Working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/Lbeycjgs/1/